# Scala Type Syntax

Tags: scala, functional-programming, type-parameter

I've observed that, if I want to make a generic function that can accept a list of any type and return a boolean, I can use the following syntax for a function declaration:

```
def someFunction[A](l:List[A]):Boolean
```

However, I can achieve an equivalent function declaration with this syntax as well:

```
def someFunction(l:List[_]):Boolean
```

The latter syntax makes sense to me; the underscore indicates a wildcard for a List of any type. However the former is confusing; what's the semantic difference between the two types of syntax, if there is one at all? Note: I noticed I could use [B] or [c] or even [%] in place of the "[A]" in the first syntax example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `A` is a "type parameter".  Just like a value parameter, such as your `l` passed parameter, it is the "name", or place holder, for a some type which might be different at different times (i.e. with different invocations of the method).

In your example the `A` is unused so, yeah, using `_` makes more sense and is clearer, but if you were to return an element from the list then the method return type would be `A` (or whatever name you want to give that parameter).  Using `_` as a return type wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

`List[_]` is an unconstrained [existential type](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#existential-types) and shorthand for `List[X] forSome {type X <: Any}` (which is like `List<?>` in Java).

In this case, I think the function types (not in Scala syntax) `forall A. List[A] -> Boolean` and `(exists A. List[A]) -> Boolean` denote the same things, since in both cases you can only inspect the "shape" of the list; probably there's an equivalence between those types.