# def layout[A](x: A) = ... syntax in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm a beginner of Scala who is struggling with Scala syntax.
I got the line of code from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/higher_order_functions.htm.

I know (x: A) is an argument of layout function
( which means argument x of Type A)

But what is [A] between layout and (x: A)?

I've been googling scala function syntax, couldn't find it.

```
def layout[A](x: A) = "[" + x.toString() + "]"
```

Comment: A is a type parameter, so it means that x can be any type of object that you pass to it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Parametric_polymorphism

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820570/scala-type-syntax).

Answer (score 8):

It's a type parameter, meaning that the method is parameterised (some also say "generic"). Without it, compiler would think that `x: A` denotes a variable of some concrete type A, and when it wouldn't find any such type it would report a compile error.

This is a fairly common thing in statically typed languages; for example, Java has the same thing, only syntax is `<A>`.

Parameterized methods have rules where the types can occur which involve concepts of covariance and contravariance, denoted as `[+A]` and `[-A]`. Variance is definitely not in the scope of this question and is probably too much for you too handle right now, but it's an important concept so I figured I'd just mention it, at least to let you know what those plus and minus signs mean when you see them (and you will).

Also, type parameters can be upper or lower bounded, denoted as `[A <: SomeType]` and `[A >: SomeType]`. This means that generic parameter needs to be a subtype/supertype of another type, in this case a made-up type `SomeType`.

There are even more constructs that contribute extra information about the type (e.g. context bounds, denoted as `[A : Foo]`, used for typeclass mechanism), but you'll learn about those later.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the method is using a **generic type** as its parameter. Every type you pass that has the definition for .toString could be passed through `layout`.

For example, you could pass both `int` and `string` arguments to layout, since you could call `.toString` on both of them.

```
val i = 1
val s = "hi"

layout(i) // would give "[1]"
layout(s) // would give "[hi]"
```

Without the gereric parameter, for this example you would have to write two definitions for layout: one that accepts integers as param, and one that accepts string as param. Even worse: every time you need another type you'd have to write another definition that accepts it.

Take a look at this example [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-write-scala-methods-generic-types-parameters-syntax) and you'll understand it better.

I also recomend you to take a look at generic classes [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/generic-classes.html).

Answer (score 0):

`A` is a type parameter. Rather than being a data type itself (Ex. `case class A`), it is generic to allow any data type to be accepted by the function. So both of these will work:

1. `layout(123f)` [Float datatype] will output: "[123]"
2. `layout("hello world")` [String datatype] will output: "[hello world]"

Hence, whichever datatype is passed, the function will allow. These type parameters can also specify rules. These are called contravariance and covariance. [Read more about them here!](http://blog.kamkor.me/Covariance-And-Contravariance-In-Scala/)